# ASP.NET MVC Form Validation. How do you do it on a non-model object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view with model `BlogPostViewModel`:

```
public class BlogPostViewModel
{
    public BlogPost BlogPost { get; set; }
    public PostComment NewComment { get; set; }
}
```

This view is rendered when action method `BlogPost` is hit. The view displays information regarding the blog post as well as a list of comments on the blog post by iterating over `Model.BlogPost.PostComments`. Below that I have a form allowing users to post a new comment. This form posts to a different action `AddComment`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddComment([Bind(Prefix = "NewComment")] PostComment postComment)
    {
        postComment.Body = Server.HtmlEncode(postComment.Body);
        postComment.PostedDate = DateTime.Now;
        postCommentRepo.AddPostComment(postComment);
        postCommentRepo.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("BlogPost", new { Id = postComment.PostID });
    }
```

My problem is with validation. How do I validate this form? The model of the view was actually `BlogPostViewModel`. I'm new to validation and am confused. The form uses the strongly-typed helpers to bind to the `NewComment` property of `BlogPostViewModel` and I included the validation helpers as well.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Blog")
{
    <div class="formTitle">Add Comment</div>
    <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NewComment.PostID) @* This property is populated in the action method for the page. *@
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewComment.Author)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewComment.Author)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Email:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewComment.Email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewComment.Email)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Website:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewComment.Website)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewComment.Website)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Body:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.NewComment.Body)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewComment.Body)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

How in the `AddComment` action method do I implement validation? When I detect `Model.IsValid == false` then what? What do I return? This action method is only binding to the `PostComment` property of the pages initial `BlogPostViewModel` object because I don't care about any other properties on that model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repopulate the model and send to view. However, you don't need to do this by hand, you can use action filters.

see:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx#prg

Specifically:

```
public abstract class ModelStateTempDataTransfer : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected static readonly string Key = typeof(ModelStateTempDataTransfer).FullName;
}

public class ExportModelStateToTempData : ModelStateTempDataTransfer
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Only export when ModelState is not valid
        if (!filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Export if we are redirecting
            if ((filterContext.Result is RedirectResult) || (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult))
            {
                filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key] = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}

public class ImportModelStateFromTempData : ModelStateTempDataTransfer
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ModelStateDictionary modelState = filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key] as ModelStateDictionary;

        if (modelState != null)
        {
            //Only Import if we are viewing
            if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
            {
                filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(modelState);
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise remove it.
                filterContext.Controller.TempData.Remove(Key);
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get), ImportModelStateFromTempData]
public ActionResult Index(YourModel stuff)
{
    return View();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), ExportModelStateToTempData]
public ActionResult Submit(YourModel stuff)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            //save
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(ModelStateException, e);
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your *AddComment* ActionResult, do this:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
 // Insert new comment
 ..
 ..
 // Redirect to a different view
}
// Something is wrong, return to the same view with the model & errors 
var postModel = new BlogPostViewModel { PostComment = postComment };
return View(postModel);
```

Comment: See though, the view we're posting from is "BlogPost", when I do `return View(postComment);` it says `The view 'AddComment' or its master was not found` which is correct because their is no view by that name.

Comment: If I do `return View("BlogPost", postComment);` it yells at me for not supplying the correct model type, which is `BlogPostViewModel`. Does this mean I have to create a `BlogPostViewModel` and return it just for validation? If so, does that also mean I have to populate the `BlogPost` property on the view model or the blog post info would disappear on the page when it renders to display the validation errors?

Comment: You can also passing in View in the parameter, i.e `return View("BlogPost", postComment");`

Comment: I was posting my comment at the same time as you post yours... See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

After much time spent I have realized that I have to repopulate the view model and render the correct view, passing in the fully-populated model. Kind of a pain but at least I understand what's going on.